# Using A* algorithm for soving sliding puzzle and N Queens?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, a-star, n-queens

I have successfully implemented A* for path finding on a grid on NxM.

I know all the basics of A* and I wanted to know how to implement the same algorithm for the mentioned problems.

Can someone guide me as to what the heuristic function h and the G score is related to in these problems and how to proceed.

-- For example in grid search we add the neighbours to the opened list and then search the lowest F score, and add it to the closed list.

What would be done to follow the same algorithm for solving NQueens and Sliding puzzle?

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you figured out what your search space is and what the nodes would look like?

Comment: umm nope? O.o Do i need to? 
Wasn't needed in grid search i guess?

Comment: In pathfinding through a grid it's very obvious, you probably figured it out without realizing that's what you were doing. But for NQueens and Sliding Puzzle, it's obviously not the same deal as pathfinding in a grid - the "steps" you take don't take you from one cell to the next, they take you from one grid to an other grid that is somehow related.

Comment: Okay so what all do i need to know to solve the those puzzles using A* ?

Comment: Ok well I guess I'll make that an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define properly your transition function, cost function and heuristic function. Instead of explaining you each example, if you know the basics about A*, you might find useful to take a look of an implementation of the [N-Queens problem](https://github.com/citiususc/hipster/blob/development/hipster-examples/src/main/java/es/usc/citius/hipster/examples/NQueensProblemExample.java) and the [N-Puzzle problem](https://github.com/citiususc/hipster/blob/development/hipster-examples/src/main/java/es/usc/citius/hipster/examples/NPuzzleProblemExample.java) of the [Hipster library](http://hipster4j.org). If you are not implementing your code in Java don't worry, the code is clear enought to let you know how to do it.

I hope my answer helps.

Adrián

Comment: Thanx a lot 
I have implemented A* successfully on the N-Puzzle using the heuristics=misplaced tiles.
but I still can't figure out the heuristics to be used for N-Queens  
:(

Comment: For this problem, in the library we use as heuristic the number of attacked queens. Take a look of how we calculate it [in the NQueens class](https://github.com/citiususc/hipster/blob/development/hipster-examples/src/main/java/es/usc/citius/hipster/examples/problem/NQueens.java). It is the method `attackedQueens()`.

Comment: I am sorry if I say anything out of context here as I am not used to github.
But the previous link that you posted consists of the Hill Climbing algorithm if I am not wrong.
Isn't it different from A* and hence wouldn't using it's heuristic in A* create issues? O.o

Comment: In the case of N-Queens, the cost function is the number of attacked queens. You can use this as heuristic too, as it is not so complex to calculate. As the heuristic and cost functions are the same, A* will find the optimal solution expanding the least possible number of states. Also, as the heuristic is the same as the cost, it is valid for the algorithm (as it is admissible and consistent).

Comment: Well Thank you very much. I'll try that out right now :)

Answer (score 3):

A* is an algorithm that works on graphs, so when you're using A* to solve a problem, that problem has to look like a graph. Of course you usually don't actually build the graph, it's usually implicit, but it's still a graph (it has nodes and the nodes have edges to neighbours).

So you have to decide what the nodes in that graph are. For pathfinding on a grid, the nodes correspond to positions in the grid.

Then you define a way (or several) to generate neighbours from a node. Thinking about the graph, that's a function from a node to a set of its outgoing edges. For pathfinding in a grid, that's the thing where you generate perhaps the 4 adjacent positions (or 8 or whatever). Basically, you define the "steps" that can be taken.

These steps have a cost. That's not G, it's just what you increment G by. Often it's just 1. To take pathfinding in a grid as example again, sometimes it's defined as 10 for a step north/east/south/west and 12 for a diagonal step (approximates Euclidean distance with small integers that are simple to work with).

Then you find [admissible heuristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) (one that does not overestimate the actual cost), which is in a way what A* is all about. Without that it would be a dumb search, the heuristic makes it informed, and it has to be admissible to ensure optimality. Finding admissible heuristics that are also good (that is, reasonably high) can be tricky. If you find several of them, say the functions `h0` and `h1`, then you can take `max(h0, h1)`, but of course that only helps if neither of them is a clear "winner" in the sense that it's always at least as high as the other (and still admissible, obviously). If there *is* a clear winner, you can obviously just use that one and forget about the other.

Basically this all is a way to "fill in the blanks" in the A* algorithm, which does not itself change depending on what problem you're solving with it .. except for one detail: the closed list can only be used if the heuristic is [consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic). So you still do the familiar thing of taking the lowest-F-score node from the open list, putting it in the closest list, looking at its neighbours and putting them in the open list, I'm skipping over a lot here but you know the drill.

Comment: Okay I think i am getting the hang of it.
Thanks a lot. :)